# Windows Server Backup to network share: Windows Backup encountered an error when accessing the remote shared folder

Tags: windows-backup, windows-server

I have configured a Windows Server Backup job whichs backs up the complete system to a network share. This works fine the first time, but the second time - when there are already some files there from the previous backup - the backup always fail.

The helpful message shown in the log:

```
Backup of volume C: has failed. Windows Backup encountered an error when accessing the remote shared folder. Please retry the operation after making sure that the remote shared folder is available and accessible.
```

It did backup something:

```
Backup of volume \\?\Volume{054c4a3c-080c-11e8-80b3-806e6f6e6963}\ succeeded.
```

I have observed this behavior on several systems virtualized on Hyper-V or not (2x DC Windows Server 2008R2, 1x DC Windows Server 2016, 1x DM Windows Server 2012R2).

Current workaround I use is clearing the entire folder on the network prior to backup, so the backup always backs up to an empty folder.

Does anyone have information to solve this issue, preferably without resorting to weird workarounds like I'm already doing? I'm also open to - preferably free - VSS based backup solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server Backup is a GUI wrapper over wbadmin.exe.

wbadmin.exe, in turn, uses the Volume Shadow Copy Service to do all the heavy lifting.

To give things the best possible chance of working:

- The Network Target (share) should be hosted on Windows 2012 R2 or later.
- The target server and client machines should be all be Active Directory members.
- The user account running the backup process should have Full Control in Share permissions as well as the underlying File System ACLs.

If you're wondering about the WS2012R2 requirement, it's because when you use VSS on share both client-side and server-side must have Resiliency Support:

> Assume that you have a computer that has Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, or Windows Server 2012 installed, and you are connected to a server share across a SMB2 link that does not support resiliency. Resiliency is an optional feature beginning with SMB 2.1 and some SMB2 implementations do not support resiliency.

REF: [Virtual hard disk cannot be created on an SMB server without resiliency support from a Windows computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2920193/virtual-hard-disk-cannot-be-created-on-an-smb-server-without-resilienc)

In my experience I've noticed VSS is also sensitive to time out issues, so it can fail randomly when either the target server or the intervening network is busy.